# Why are MongoDB upserts so much slower than inserts (with a unique index)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance

I've been testing the limits of MongoDB to see whether it will work for an upcoming project and I've noticed that upserts are quite slow compared to inserts.

Of course, I'd expect them to be slower, but not (almost) an order of magnitude slower (7400 vs 55000 ops/sec). Here's the (nodejs native driver) bench-marking code that I used:

```
(async function() {

  let db = await require('mongodb').MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mongo-benchmark-8764824692947');
  db.collection('text').createIndex({text:1},{unique:true})

  let batch = db.collection('text').initializeOrderedBulkOp();
  let totalOpCount = 0;
  let batchOpCount = 0;
  let start = Date.now();
  while(1) {

    totalOpCount++;
    batchOpCount++;
    if(batchOpCount === 1000) { // batch 1000 ops at a time
      await batch.execute();
      batch = db.collection('text').initializeOrderedBulkOp();
      batchOpCount = 0;
      let secondsElapsed = (Date.now() - start)/1000;
      console.log(`(${Math.round(totalOpCount/secondsElapsed)} ops per sec) (${totalOpCount} total ops)`)
    }

    /////////  INSERT TEST  ///////// (~55000 ops/sec)
    // batch.insert({text:totalOpCount});

    /////////  UPSERT TEST  ///////// (~7400 ops/sec)
    let text = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000);
    batch.find({text}).upsert().updateOne({$setOnInsert:{text}});

    if(totalOpCount > 500000) {
      console.log("<< finished >>");
      await db.dropCollection('text');
      db.close();
      break;
    }

  }

})();
```

You can easily run it yourself by pasting it into `index.js`, running `npm init -y` and `npm install --save mongodb` and then `node .`

When we `upsert` a document, the mongo engine has to check whether there's an existing document that matches it. This might have explained some of the slowdown, but doesn't an `insert` command on a unique index require the same collision checking? Thanks!

**Edit:** Turns out `$setOnInsert` *is* needed else we get duplicate key errors.

Comment: When upserting a document indeed two main operation would be done. 1st is find and 2nd is update/insert. Also of course you might try an [unorderedBulkOperation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/UnorderedBulkOperation.html)

Comment: Wouldn't the `insert` need a `find` too since it's a unique index (i.e. to prevent duplicate keys)? Or is there some other magic that `insert` uses? Ah thanks for the tip on `unorder`ing the batch operation. Strangely enough that barely affected the performance in the code I've posted above, but it did double the performance of some other code I'm using!

Comment: interesting, looks like index on `text` field is ineffective here. Can you comment `await db.dropCollection('text');` and try with explain on a manual `upsert`? That might give some insights. I'm good at nodejs so can't run your code. But, to the core it looks like a database issue than an application issue. I'll run in my local and let you know the result.

Comment: That syntax in the update doesn't look right: `{$set:{text}}`. Shouldn't it be `{$set:{"text" : text}}` ?

Comment: @VinceBowdren Oh, that's a JavaScript ES6 shorthand, sorry `{$set:{text}} === {$set:{text:text}} === {$set:{"text":text}}` ([explanation](https://ariya.io/2013/02/es6-and-object-literal-property-value-shorthand)). @harshavmb, I'm not exactly sure what you mean, sorry - how does one `.explain()` a bulk operation? I tried and got `batch.execute(...).explain is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

I made each batch bigger by changing `if(batchOpCount === 1000)` to `if(batchOpCount === 50000)`, and got ~**90000** ops/sec for `insert` and ~**35000** ops/sec for `upsert`. I'm not exactly sure why the batch size makes a *relative* difference. It makes sense that smaller batches would result in fewer ops/sec (communication overhead), but I'm not sure why `upserts` suffer more than `inserts`, though this is probably a topic for a separate question.

This (roughly) 3-fold speed difference is definitely closer to the performance difference between the two operations that I'd expect, but it still seems like `upserts` are a little slower than they should be, given that inserts must also check for collisions (due to the unique index). This is really only a half-answer, so I'm going to leave this question open in the hope that a mongo pro will come along and provide a more complete answer.